# jQuery function not executed with new parameter

Tags: jquery

My function was working as intended, but then I added an additonnal parameter to the function. I want to associate different XML files to different divs of my HTML. This is how I tried to do it:

```
function request(){
 rssRequest();
rssRequest2();
}
    function rssRequest(){
         let url = "https://news.google.com/rss?x=1571747254.2933&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en";
                let idContent = "world";
                $.ajax(url, {
                        method: "GET",
                        type: 'xml',
                        success: useContent($, idContent)
                     }
            )
        }

        function useContent(xmlContent, id){
            let $items = $(xmlContent).find("item");

                $items.each(function(){
                    let title = $(this).find('title').text();
        let h3 = $("<'h3'>" +title+ "</'h3'>");
        article.append(h3)
        $("#"+id).append(article)
            })
        }
```

Adding an alert to my code, I found out that the code after  `$items.each(function(){` is not executed. How can I execute it?

Comment: can you put `console.log($items)` right after declaring it and show the results?

Comment: I get this .fn.init `[prevObject: k.fn.init(1)` twice because 2 functions calls useContent. It worked before I added another parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `useContent()` before AJAX request happens. So the function doesn't receive proper parameters.

My solution to solve the problem is that use an anonymous function to pass proper arguments.

```js
function rssRequest() {
  let url =
    "https://news.google.com/rss?x=1571747254.2933&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"
  let idContent = "world"
  $.ajax(url, {
    method: "GET",
    type: "xml",
    success: function(content) {
      useContent(content, idContent)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this was the issue! Is there a way to find out how my program execute step-by-step so I can easily find these kind of problem? Or I need to analyse my code better...

Comment: @Ron Chrome has a debugger that you can see the execution steps. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

Comment: Sorry, the page above is deprecated. I've found a newer article about the debugger. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon and closing bracket on $.ajax({..}); (at the end, just before the function useContent). Your code should look like this:

```js
let url = "https://news.google.com/rss?x=1571747254.2933&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en";

let idContent = "world";

$.ajax(url, {
    method: "GET",
    type: 'xml',
    success: useContent($, idContent)
});

function useContent(xmlContent, id){
    let $items = $(xmlContent).find("item");

    $items.each(function(){
        let title = $(this).find('title').text();
        let h3 = $("<'h3'>" +title+ "</'h3'>");
        article.append(h3);
        $("#"+id).append(article);
    });
}
```